# How to create Datadog pie charts from property data?

Tags: parsing, charts, datadog

So, using Datadog is proving to be quite difficult when attempting to parse some of the data we have.

For example, imagine we have a log that has the properties

| Type | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Cat | 3 |
| Dog | 4 |

How do we get a Datadog dashboard to appreciate this data? I have full control over how the data is added to the log but I don't know how to iterate over it or parse it in a meaningful manner

For example, it may come out like

`Animals:[{"Cat":3},{"Dog":4}]`